# How to test whether Linux is running on a ThinkPad?

Tags: linux, thinkpad, dmesg

#### I need to programmatically detect if Linux is running on a ThinkPad.

A shell script would be *ideal* but I can programmatically generate any binary by downloading some source and compiling it on the machine if only a custom program will be able to *reliably* do that.

Focus is: **reliability/accuracy**. If in doubt, I prefer *not* to run the script.

I have a hunch this may be cleverly done using text parsing of things like dmesg or `lshw`, but which method is the most reliable?

**Restriction**: run as a normal user, as part of a login script, no possibility of temporarily elevating privileges just to detect the machine model.

**Permission**: take as long as needed, speed is not a factor.

**Environment**: Ubuntu, but Linux generality is nice to have. Availability of developer-level build tools (GCC can be assumed to "just work"). The login script is run by bash so a code snippet in that syntax would be more directly usable.

Comment: As far as I can understand, you want to make sure you are on Linux using a shell script. I guess `uname -o # --operating-system` may help. I'm on Ubuntu 13.4 latest, and it reports `GNU/Linux`.

Comment: @gkya He doesn't: he wants to make sure he's on Linux running on a ThinkPad machine.

Comment: You might be able to do `dmesg` or `lspci -v` and then grep (IBM|Lenovo) on their output.

Answer (score 2):

The following works on my Lenovo ThinkPad (Running FC17):

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_vendor
```

Prints:

```
LENOVO
```

The following directory can be checked for `/proc/acpi/ibm/`.  You could look in `/proc/acpi/ibm/driver` for "ThinkPad ACPI Extras".

Answer (score 0):

dmidecode can provide this information.  It however requires root privileges to access /dev/mem, so due to your restrictions this can not be used directly.

You have two options.

A) Log in as root and run `dmidecode -t system > /var/tmp/dmidecode_system`
Then ensure that the file is world readable and check the contents of that file in the user's login script.

The problem is that the information will only be updated "manually".  You could however simply update it from an init script.

B) A more "live" option is to create a little tool which provides the required information to non-priviledged processes.

First create an interface, eg `mkfifo /var/tmp/dmidecode_read`

Then spawn a process which will write the information every time someone requests it, eg

```
while true; do dmidecide -t system > /var/tmp/dmidecode_read; done
```

In this case this will work, because you can not replace a motherboard while the system is running.  But for completeness' sake I mention that this information could still theoretically become stale.  Each time a a user reads from the pipe, the current buffer is emptied, the sleeping "supplier" exists, a and then after the reader received the existing buffer, a new "supplier" will be spawned and it will put fresh information into the buffer ready for the next reader, whenever that will be.

Comment: It's probably easier to make `dmidecode` setuid

Comment: That would violate the "do not temporarily increase privileges" requirement.